# Random query execution time

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I develop web application (ASP.NET Core, EF Core, SQL Server).

Database table contains < 20 rows for now (I mean not so much entries).

EF Core method to access data:

```
public IQueryable<Player> GetSuitablePlayers()
{
    IQueryable<Player> list = _context.Players
        .Include(x => x.ImagePhoto)
        .Include(x => x.FirstCoach)
        .Include(x => x.PlayerTags);

    return list;
}
```

Every time I request the same URL (hit <kbd>F5</kbd> in browser for example), execution time of SQL query is random sometimes (not always). I measure it in SQL Server Profiler.

Please see screenshot here:

[image]

`Duration` column can be anywhere from 0 to 25 seconds. I do not use any cache techniques. All settings are default (DbContext, ChangeTracker etc).

1. What am I doing wrong? Too many `.Include` calls? Not using DTOs or anonymous types in C# to access database data?
2. What is the `Reads` column responsible for? Its value correlates with the response time.

Comment: When you first run a query once you start the application, it takes more time because of ef core's behind the scenes and handshake with the database

Comment: The portion of the query visible in Profiler suggests that there's much more to this SQL Query than what's visible in your C# code example - there are at least five tables involved. What is the full query generated? What are the DDL statements for all those tables - and their indexes? Have you captured an Actual Execution Plan yet to see how SQL Server is choosing to respond to this query? You can use [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) to share that.